# ASP.NET site Determine if running on Test vs Prod envirnoment

Tags: asp.net, deployment, development-environment, production-environment

I have a Webforms site that is deployed in test, staging and production.

Some internal users are having difficulty keeping track of which site they are.

I have a master page and common header/footers for every page.

How would I make text like "TEST" or "STAGING" appear on the pages in those environments, but still be able to deploy the same code base to production?

Comment: Try using a descriptive URL?

Comment: staging.mydomain.com - prod.mydomain.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") and just create some if logic that changes your page title (or whatever indicator you want to use) to say dev or test ( i usually leave prod just blank)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to differentiate the two environments is with a different banner for each. Alternatively, use descriptive URLs such as:

staging.mydomain.com

prod.mydomain.com

Comment: They would have different URLS because they reside on different servers. It is the ways of loading a different banner that I'm interested in.

Comment: Use Limey's suggestion and toggle it accordingly.